# Ruby on Rails: What is the convention (is there one?) for creating a model instance programmatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model: '**event**' and it has a controller: '**event_controller**'

The **event_controller** handles the following route: **events/:id/complete_event**

In the controller, I need to trigger the creation a couple other model objects in the system, which are calculated and not inputted via a web form.

In this case the models to create are:

1. **score** (which belongs_to: *user* and *event*)
2. **stats** (which belongs_to: *event*)
3. **standing** (which belongs_to: *user* | and is based on the new *score*/*stats* object)

What is the convention for this type of model creation for Ruby on Rails?

Is it okay for the **event_controller** to create these (somewhat unrelated) model objects?

or,

Should the event_controller call into the **score_controller**, **stats_controller** and **standing_controller**?

With the second option, I am concerned that it will not work to dispatch 2-3 routes in a chain to create all the objects in their corresponding controllers but is that is the convention.

In the end, it's ideal to redirect the user back to show_event view, which will display the **event** and its associated **scores** and **stats** objects.

Code for the **event_controller** method: **complete_event**

```
def complete_event
  event = Event.find(params[:id])
  if event.in_progress?
    event.complete!
  end
  # 1. create score for each user in event.users
  # 2. create stats for the event
  # 3. update the overall standings for each score (per user)
  redirect_to event
end
```

As you can see, the event is not being creating on this action, rather the event state is updated to 'complete' this is the trigger to create the associated records.

The commented lines above represent what I need to do after event is complete; I am just not sure that this is where I go ahead and ***directly*** create the objects.

E.g. To create **score** will I have to calculate a lot of data that starts in event, but uses many models to get all the relevant data to create it.

Comment: Yes, controllers can create whatever models they want. Nothing prevents them from doing so. They must not call other controllers directly. Only indirectly, via `redirect_to` or something. I suggest that you read more of rails guides/tutorials. Apparently, the concepts are still a bit fuzzy in your head.

Comment: I would argue that this shouldn't be done in a controller at all. Instead your controller could call a Builder that creates all related and associated objects within one method. Or your event model could generate all required coupled objects itself when it is created. Or it could create them lazily when you access them for the first time.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have researched Rails guides and have been following several tutorials; but none really highlight or address this particular scenario.  If you have any reference links that would be helpful.

Comment: @spickermann I will look into using a Builder. I have updated the question to reflect the code that I am addressing. The event is not being created, rather updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the whole logic out of controller so what i can understand when you call even.completed! you need to create score for users and update the over all ratings. So add call back in your model after_update is_event_completed! assuming evet.completed! will mark the event complete at db level. Then just place the corresponding logic in your model. It's the best practice to place your business logic into your model. Here is a nice gem to manage states of a model github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine and do specific stuff on specific events.

Comment: You can move the whole logic out of controller so what i can understand when you call even.completed! you need to create score for users and update the over all ratings. So add call back in your model after_update is_event_completed! assuming evet.completed! will mark the event complete at db level. Then just place the corresponding logic in your model. It's the best practice to place your business logic into your model. Here is a nice gem to manage states of a model https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine and do specific stuff on specific events.

Comment: Thanks Muaaz Rafi, I have edited the question to include the code around the state update.

Answer (score 0):

It feels to me that all the steps are part of completing an event, therefore I think it belongs into the `Event#complete!` method.

```
# in the controller
def complete_event
  event = Event.find(params[:id])
  event.complete! if event.in_progress?
  redirect_to event
end

# in the model
def complete!
  # complete event

  # 1. create score for each user in event.users
  # 2. create stats for the event
  # 3. update the overall standings for each score (per user)
end
```

Or you could use a small Ruby class that performs the completion:

```
# in the controller
def complete_event
  event = Event.find(params[:id])
  EventCompleter.new(event).perform
  redirect_to event
end

# in models/event_completer.rb
class EventCompleter < Struct.new(:event)
  def perform
    event.complete!

    # 1. create score for each user in event.users
    # 2. create stats for the event
    # 3. update the overall standings for each score (per user)
  end
end
```

The second seems a bit too complex for this simple example, but is an interesting pattern for more complex tasks. Main benefit is that this simple Ruby class encapsulates all business and domain logic that need to be done, when completing an event (this logic doesn't not really belong to events). And it it easier to test.